# How can html5 routing be achieved in angular2?

Tags: angular, angular-routing

In angular 1, I can enable/disable the html routing with $routeProvider. How can that be achieved in angular 2 with direct url access to the page?

Comment: That's the default in Angular2. You can disable it by setting `LocationStrategy` to `HashLocationStrategy`.

Answer (score -1):

`RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true })`

explained here https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#browser-url-styles